# Titanium uitableview can't scroll up with search enable (Android)

Tags: uitableview, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

When i scroll down and release, i can't scroll up again, i have got this issue on **android**

My sdk version is **5.1**

Here is my **search**,

```
var search = Titanium.UI.createSearchBar({
  barColor: '#fb2942',
  showCancel: true,
  top: 0,
  hintText: 'Search....',
});

table.search = search;

table.filterAttribute = 'title';

if (OS_ANDROID) {
  table.searchHidden = false;
} else {
  table.searchHidden = false;
}

table.separatorColor = "#ddd";

search.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  e.value;
});
search.addEventListener('return', function(e) {
  search.blur();
});
search.addEventListener('cancel', function(e) {
  search.blur();
});
```

And here is my **tableview**,

```
var table = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  separatorColor: "#ddd",
  separatorInsets: {
    left: 0,
    right: 0
  },
  top: '8dp',
  height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
});
```

Comment: I think this is happening because of tableview height. Set table.height = '70%' and try again.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be scrollable the TableView `height` must be set to its default `Ti.UI.FILL` or a fixed/percentage width, but **not** `Ti.UI.SIZE` since that will cause it to fit its content, at which point there's nothing to scroll ;)

Comment: Actually i found that this is happening because of the pull to refresh view i'm using..it conflicts when the search is enable on the tableview.